# MySQL - Which one is faster - Joining 2 tables by 1 key or 2 keys?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, key

We are in the process of designing the database. Supposed that we have 2 tables A and B. At the moment they have 2 columns x and y that contain the same information - In other words, we can join A and B on A.x == B.x and A.y == B.y.

One idea is that, we should pre-process table A so that it contain z and A.z = B.id. The pre-processing is done in background only. Now we can join 2 table on A.z == B.id.

Which JOIN will be faster? (We don't take into account time for pre-processing).

UPDATE:

- About indexing: Yes, for solution 1 I indexed (A.x, A,y) and (B.x, B.y). For solution 2 I indexed A.z and B.id.
- My data is big.

Comment: This depends on whether you have well defined indexes on the columns concerned. It will not matter then, because when the database can use the index it will have both values stored in one "key" in the index.

Comment: The z option may be fractionally faster on a vast data set, but for most practical purposes there will be no difference, and the overhead or maintenance/pre-processing should not be discounted.

Comment: If I were u I would populate the db and then query and see which one works the best. Also there are many more factors which you need to consider I am sure you are aware of like query caching, index and variables

Comment: @trincot: Yes my data is very big. What I want is: When user trigger query, it should return as fast as possible. Pre-processing can be done beforehand in background, so user don't have to wait for time to pre-process. I already index on the B.id, A.z and also (A.x and A.y) and (B.x and B.y)

Answer (score 2):

I have situation same to you with big data. And the z option is faster. You have to defined index on the column z.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same pairs (x,y) in both tables, you have (in a perverse way) redundant information.  Redundancy is a no-no in "proper" database design.

Background tasks like what you describe are problematical, so I see that as a design destined to cause trouble.

Can't you set `A.z` immediately?  That would be the best.  Please should show us the actual tables; often the column names lead to other discussions, that lead to other solutions.

An example of such is `x DATE, y TIME` -- it is very often bad to split a DATETIME into two columns.

Comment: x is user_id, y is date_time. A and B are joined by (user_id, date_time). z is id of one row in table B. You can call it b_id.